# IMCE module is not showing icons on the editor

Tags: 6, media

I installed the [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) module, but it didn't add any icon to the editor menu toolbar. It manually loads with domain.com/imce.

Comment: What module are you using. You probably need to turn IMCE on from wysiwyg profiles.

Comment: To get a proper reaction you should supply more setup information, like the module you are trying to integrate IMCE on.

Answer (score 0):

You need [IMCE WYSIWYG bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) module to connect it with WYSIWYG editor.

For CKEditor, configure the editor for your input filter and choose "IMCE" button.

For TinyMCE it is enough to select "Image" button.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CKeditor instead of the wysiwyg bridge.